# Как вывести количество положительных оценок (Оценка > 2) по определённым предметам за экзамен?

Tags: sql-server

Таблица предметов [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Таблица экзаменов

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выводит проведенные экзамены, и количество всех оценок за этот экзамен. Как вывести количество положительных оценок за определённый экзамен ?

---

```
SELECT 
    SubjName AS 'Предмет', COUNT(Mark) AS 'Количество оценок'
FROM Subject
JOIN ExamMarks ON (Subject.IdSubj = ExamMarks.IdSubj)
GROUP BY SubjName;
```

Comment: Например, можно вместо `COUNT(Mark)` написать `SUM(CASE WHEN Mark > 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`.

Comment: Спасибо большое )